# Synchronisation not working. How do I fix that?

Tags: ubuntu-one, tomboy

As you no doubt know, Ubuntu One and Tomboy LOOK really great. But performance on sync has been chewing painfully at me for months. When I try to sync my notes it tells me it can't and there's nothing in the details pane.

I've searched through forums and found no solution that works.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do. The service is a little bit unstable, presently. We'll just have to hope it gets better soon. Specially the couch service.